# LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001 even with PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

Tags: python, python-unicode

In my program i eval a Python function that generates a unicode(random alphabet ) and print it out.

In the cmd line i have 
chcp 65001
SET PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

On my VM i get the error: LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001

but on my laptop it works fine, anyone know why i might get the LookupError on another machine?

Python 2.7.14 (32bit)

```
    cs = string.ascii_lowercase
    result = unicode(''.join(random.sample(cs,5)))
    print result
```

Comment: Is it to late to convince you to switch to Python3? Also looks like you misspelled `PYTHONIOENCODING`*  :)

Comment: python 3 is not an option. Made a typo in my initial post :)

Comment: Not sure what the relevance of python vs the lookup error here is. It's most likely that one machine has English and use UTF-8 and the other some other locale installed which uses `65002`. And that would explain why you get a lookup error for that. But, if you could, please post the full stack trace, and separate your `chcp 65001` commands and show us the full commands executed, not abbreviations of it. It would help a lot trying to help you here. For instance, show (text form) line by line how you execute your terminal, and your script.